# SQL query to check the count

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a column in bigquery which is time in the below format. The time(time is in utc) increases in 15 minute interval(starting from 00:10) and it continues for the whole day till 23:.....

```
00:10   
00:25   
00:40   
...
```

now i want to check if we have data uptodate using a query. That is every time point we should have multiple entries(count should be >0 when grouped by time). If there is no count at a particular point my query should be returning a flag whih raises that.
if we are running the query at 01:05 we know that there should be four points(00:10 00:25 00:40 00:55) with non zero count
How do we compare and ensure this using a query?

```
select timecolumn as time, count(*) as cnt 
from 'project.dataset.table' 
group by 1 
order by 1
```

will give the below

```
00:10     5 
00:25     5
00:40     10

....



select timecolumn as time, count(*) as cnt 
from 'project.dataset.table'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you can skip `group by` and do something like shown below.

Number of rows returned by `required_times` will grow from 0 to a max of 24*4 records during the day.

`my_data_table` is just for emulating your data table. You may need to apply `timestamp_trunc(timecolumn, MINUTE)` for your data if it does not match exactly with values from `required_times`.

```
with required_times as (
  select * from unnest(GENERATE_TIMESTAMP_ARRAY(
    date_add(timestamp_trunc(current_timestamp(), DAY), INTERVAL 10 MINUTE), 
    current_timestamp(), 
    INTERVAL 15 MINUTE)) as timecolumn
),
my_data_table as (
  select * from unnest(GENERATE_TIMESTAMP_ARRAY(
    date_add(timestamp_trunc(current_timestamp(), DAy), INTERVAL 10 MINUTE), 
    date_add(current_timestamp(), INTERVAL -1 HOUR), 
    INTERVAL 15 MINUTE)) as timecolumn
)

select
  required_times.timecolumn
from
  required_times
  left join my_data_table on required_times.timecolumn = my_data_table.timecolumn
where
  my_data_table.timecolumn is null
```

will return e.g. like this because records for the last hour of day is missing from my_data_table

[image]

Comment: perfect.  However required_times should be generated dynamically based on current time in utc. It should start in 00:10 and increment with 15 minutes interval.

Comment: @bionicsparv Updated my answer, hope this will solve it. BR

Comment: Just one more thing. The time should start at start of the day 00:10 till 23:40(end of the day). In the updated version the required_times get generated for 1 hour in the current timestamp

Comment: @bionicsparv: Updated my answer again and added some explanation. BR